# Decoding nsstring into Kenji on ios using objective c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS app and I'm getting data from an api using javascript

I created a callback method in js file and it works fine
the problem is that the data is in Kenji (Japanese) when I print it into WKwebview it's correct but when I use nslog I get a result like this one :

**q%E3%0CI%02%F60f%DF!**

I couldn't figure out how to decode those character

any one have an idea ?!

Comment: Kenji?  That's a Japanese male name.  Meanwhile, there are several text encoders.  You have to pick one.

Comment: show me your coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution i just encoded the text in js

```
var textEncoded = encodeURIComponent(text);
```

and then in my iOS app i just used this on

```
NSString *unencodedUrlString = [text stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```